# How does ties.method argument of R's rank function work?

Tags: r, ranks, ties

I am using `rank(a, ties.method="max")` to rank a. But I am not quite sure what does `ties.method="max"` do. Can you please help?

Comment: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/rank.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ties.method specifies the method rank uses to break ties. Suppose you have a vector c(1,2,3,3,4,5). It's obvious that 1 is first, and 2 is second. However, it's not clear what ranks should be assigned to the first and second 3s. Ties.method determines how this is done. There are a few options:

- average assigns each tied element the "average" rank. The ranks would therefore be 1, 2, 3.5, 3.5, 5, 6
- first lets the "earlier" entry "win", so the ranks are in numerical order (1,2,3,4,5,6)
- min assigns every tied element to the lowest rank, so you get 1,2,3,3,5,6
- max does the opposite: tied elements get the highest rank (1,2,4,4,5,6)
- random breaks ties randomly, so you'd get either (1,2,3,4,5,6) or (1,2,4,3,5,6).

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me solve my problem! Thank you again!

Comment: No problem. You may already know this, but `?command` will print the help for a command.